# What are the incompatibilities of libjingle and XEP-0166 et al?

Tags: voip, xmpp, libjingle

[libjingle's developer guide](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/developer_guide.html) quite vaguely mentions incompatibilities between libjingle's implementation of Jingle and XEP-0166's specification. It also mentions it is incompatible with XEP-0167, XEP-0176 and XEP-0177.

It never goes into detail what these differences are; in fact, it is unclear if perhaps these differences have been resolved.

What are the differences between XEPs and libjingle's implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dug out specs for Google Talk's implementation (that is, the "old" libjingle): [Google Talk Call Signaling](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/call_signaling.html). Compare with: [XEP-0166](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html)

Not only that, but it appears [Google finally updated libjingle to 0.5](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/wiki/FAQ.wiki?spec=svn36&r=32) to support both [GTCS](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/call_signaling.html) and [XEP-0166](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html).

I'll be accepting my own answer; nonetheless, a "thank you" goes to liori!

Answer (score 1):

`libjingle` exists for more than 3 years, and its protocol didn't change much. It was compatible with one of the early versions of XEP-0166... not sure now which one exactly, but I guess it was something around 0.15.

You might have better luck asking at the [jdev mailing list](http://mail.jabber.org/mailman/listinfo/jdev).

All versions of this XEP are stored in a [version control repository](http://xmpp.org/xsf/sourcecontrol.shtml).

Anyway, many implementations use libjingle, so being compatible with libjingle might be more important for you than with XEP.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait to see if someone else replies before I go comparing the specs in SVN (digging in with the CLI client is not fun), and asking on mailing list isn't fun, requiring registration when I'll only ask one question and be done with it. I'm just interested in approximate differences, and perhaps with specification of GTalk's implementation, so I can plan if I'll even bother with writing a client. libjingle as it is is not fun, trying to be an XMPP client itself, instead of just generating stanzas. I also didn't find it very readable.

Comment: @Ivan Vučica: Me neither. I tried to use it 3 years ago to add VoIP to Gajim, and failed. It helped a bit that I didn't use libjingle explicitly, but using a GStreamer wrapper called `farsight`... which has sane API, even though quite unstable at the time. I also did not use `libjingle`'s jabber client, but implemented XMPP stanzas by hand... only delegating the low-level audio transmission part to `libjingle`.