# Libjingle and jingle

Tags: xmpp, google-talk, libjingle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the incompatibilities of libjingle and XEP-0166 et al?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958340/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-libjingle-and-xep-0166-et-al)

How does std. jingle file transfer differ from its implementation in gtalk client?

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958340/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-libjingle-and-xep-0166-et-al/4003176#4003176). Signaling protocol has changed, and you can compare XEP-0166 with Google's document to see what has changed.